# JS function to create a dropdown filled with names from a DB onclick?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need help writing this small piece of code. I need a function that creates a dropdown menu that is filled with names from a Database when a button is clicked. The names in the dropdown list will eventually be submitted to a different table in the database, so I need to know how to set the names as "vales" in the dropdown list also. What would be the best way to go about implementing these issues? I've commented out where I think things should go.

Javascript:

```
var room = 1;

function ReviewForm() {
    room++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('ReviewForm')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass" + room);
    var rdiv = 'removeclass' + room;
    divtest.innerHTML = 
    '<hr>' +
        '<h2>Student:</h2>' +
        '<select>' +
        //Instead of these three names, I need to use the DB's info go generate the text and values
        '<option value="Adam">Adam</option>     ' +
        '<option value="Bob">Bob</option>       ' +
        '<option value="Cat">Cat</option>' +
        '</select></h2>' +
   objTo.appendChild(divtest)
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
         $NumberOfStudents = "";
        // $NumberOfStudents=$_GET['SelectedStudents'];


        $hostname = "host";
        $username = "user";
        $password = "pass";
        $databaseName = "_db";
        $conn ;


        $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
        /*if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} */

        //BELOW IS THE QUERY FROM THE DB THAT I AM TRYING TO GET TO REPRINT EACH TIME THE FUNCTION IS CALLED

        $query = "SELECT concat (FirstName,' ', LastName) as StudentNames FROM `Student`";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 

         ?>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <!-- Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Main -->
        <div id="main">
            <div class="inner">
                <!-- Content -->
                <section>
                    <!-- Form -->
                    <form method="post" action="#">
                        <div class="row uniform">
                            <!-- Break -->
                            <div class="12u$">
                                <div style="height:550px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;"><!-- container for reviews-->
                                    <div id="ReviewForm">
                                        <hr>
                                        <h2>
                                    Student:
                                    <select>
                                    <!-- It is hardcoded into the page here, which is fine, but I would rather it generate when the page is loaded, and then can
                                    be called again each time a new dropdown is needed. -->
                                       <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
                                       <option value="<?php echo $row1['StudentNames'];?>"><?php echo $row1['StudentNames'];?></option>
                                       <?php endwhile;?>
                                    </select>
                                 </h2>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
                    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1" />
                    <div class="control-group" id="fields">
                        <label class="control-label" for="field1"></label>
                        <div class="controls" id="profs">
                            <form class="input-group-btn">
                                <div>
                                <!--Here is the button that calls the function for a new dropdown menu-->
                                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="ReviewForm();">Add another student</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried jquery ajax? You would give the <select> element an id, make the options in the background and load them into the select element as data from the ajax callback function. Or more help?